# Scroll modal window using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape links to song pages for some artists on genius.com, but I'm running into issues because the links to the individual song pages are displayed inside a popup modal window.

The modal window doesn't load all links in one go, and instead loads more content via ajax when you scroll down to the bottom of the modal.

I tried using code to scroll to the bottom of the page but unfortunately that just scrolled in the window behind the modal rather than the modal itself:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

So then I tried selecting the last element in the modal and scrolling to that (with the idea of doing that a few times until all song pages had been loaded), but it wouldn't scroll far enough to get the website to load more content

```
last_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="mini_card-metadata"]')[-1]
last_element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
```

Here is my code so far:

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_driver = "/Applications/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chrome_driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver)

base_url = 'https://genius.com/artists/Stormzy'
driver.get(base_url)

xpath_str = '//div[contains(text(),"Show all songs by Stormzy")]'
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_str).click()
```

Is there a way to extract all the song page links for the artist?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code to get required output:

```
from selenium import webdriver as web
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver = web.Chrome()
base_url = 'https://genius.com/artists/Stormzy'
driver.get(base_url)

# Open modal
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[normalize-space()="Show all songs by Stormzy"]').click()
song_locator = By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.mini_card.mini_card--small'
# Wait for first XHR complete
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(song_locator))
# Get current length of songs list
current_len = len(driver.find_elements(*song_locator))

while True:
    # Load new XHR until it's possible
    driver.find_element(*song_locator).send_keys(Keys.END)
    try:
        wait(driver, 3).until(lambda x: len(driver.find_elements(*song_locator)) > current_len)
        current_len = len(driver.find_elements(*song_locator))
    # Return full list of songs
    except TimeoutException:
        songs_list = [song.get_attribute('href') for song in driver.find_elements(*song_locator)]
        break

print(songs_list)
```

This should allow you to request new `XHR` until length of songs list became constant and finally return the list of links

Answer (score 0):

When you scroll to bottom of modal dialog it call

```
$scrollable_data_ctrl.load_next();
```

As option you can try execute it until new results appear in modal

```
driver.execute_script("$scrollable_data_ctrl.load_next();")
```